# How to get software development job offer in Australia before immigrating (to get 5 extra points)?

Tags: working-visas, resident-permit, australia, job-hunting, interview

This is my first post in this community. Not sure if this is suitable to ask this here.

I am a software developer in the Research and Development section of a Pvt Ltd company in India. I want to move to Australia with a permanent resident visa (or not). I have taken the **IELTS** and got **overall band 7**.

I understand that I need to **retake the test**. But even if I do get a higher band and get PR, I won't feel secure to move to a different country (rather continent) without a job.

How can I get a job in a foreign country before moving there? Because if I have a job offer, it makes the process both easier and faster by increasing 5 points in the [Australia Permanent Residency Immigration Points](https://www.am22tech.com/australia-points-calculator-for-skills-based-permanent-residency-application/).

I am trying LinkedIn day-n-night but no luck getting a response.

Any suggestions?

*I know this might sound like duplicate of [this question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/497/how-to-get-a-job-in-australia-before-i-go-there), but it is NOT. The answer to the said question ends up telling that there is **no way of getting job from outside**, which is not what I want. Here I am asking for **HOW TO GET** from outside of Australia to get those 5 points*

Comment: What you can do is have some savings to cover you there for 6 months or so and then look out for a job there. People are more likely to hire you if you are in the country. And get any job while you can so that you are not depleting your savings entirely.

Comment: @DipenShah While that's true... I am looking for what can be done to find a job from India. I agree if I won't find a job from here I will  have to take up the above said way.

Comment: -1 Duplicate of the question you've linked to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a job in Australia before I go there?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/497/how-to-get-a-job-in-australia-before-i-go-there)

Comment: How is this _not_ a duplicate of the linked question?  Both you and the other asker want to know how to get a job in Australia from outside Australia.  That question has good answers with links to Australian job websites.

Comment: Still a duplicate, getting 5 extra points is a consequences of getting the job. Take some time to review the answers to the other question and realize that there is no magic answer to this. Finding a job in a foreign country without possessing a work authorization or the language skills is an uphill task.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?l=Australia&d=100&u=Miles&v=true

Answer (score 1):

**LinkedIn** is the **best way** to get a Job for professionals. There are chances (very low) that you get a interview call from Linked despite having no PR. This would require your skills in particular field of work which might attract employers to contact you. There are n direct way of getting a job offer from another country if you are not worth it

Comment: I agree to that, Which is why I had started with the jobs portal of LinkedIn at the first place. Did not work for me. Are there other Job portals which Australian companies refer to and I can apply through there?